# Post on facebook wall from Java WebService

Tags: facebook, web-services, facebook-wall

I am looking for a way to publish stuff on my facebook wall from a java-webservice.

I was looking around and found that there WAS offline_access that is now deprecated.

So...
How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options I can think of:

1. Get a long lived user access token (using [server-side](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) authentication, or [client-side](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) and then [extending the token](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)) when the user interacts with you app, then you have a valid token for 60 days.
   When the 60 days are over you'll need the user to re-engage your app to get a new token.
2. You can ask for the `publish_stream` permission and then using an [app token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) you can post on the users' behalf:

> App access tokens can also be used to publish content to Facebook on
>   behalf of a user who has granted a publishing permission to your
>   application.
>
> App Access Tokens generally do not expire. Once generated, they are
>   valid indefinitely.

Comment: You can [authenticate as a page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) but I'm not sure if you can get a long lived token for pages, I've never tried.